# Libspotify available for FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, spotify

let me start by saying I am not a programmer but only a end user. 
I dont know if anyone has formally made a request about this, but I would really like if libspotify would be made available for FreeBSD. This way someone could build an application or service to use Spotify on Freenas- and NAS4Free-based servers. 
Thanks
Renato Laus

Answer (score 0):

I think that libspotify could be made available for FreeBSD if there was sufficient demand for it, but I wouldn't expect it to happen in the near future. In the meantime, you could check out [FreeBSD's Linux binary emulation](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/linuxemu.html), as libspotify does support 32/64 bit Linux.

However, if you absolutely need a native library, I would suggest contacting Spotify and seeing what their plans are for this platform.